# I want to make a paragraph under a heading

Tags: html, css

so I'm sorta new to CSS, not that new I've been doing web development for around a month. I'm trying to make this text go below the heading with my name, heres my css and html for reference

```css
.coologo {
  width: 230px;
  border: white;
  border-radius: 6969px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
  margin: 45px;
  display: inline;
}

.about {
  background-color: #202225;
  width: 80vw;
  height: auto;
  margin: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  justify-content: center;
}

.about:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.name {
  font-family: "Red Hat Display", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  display: table-row;
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
}

.occupation {
  font-family: "Red Hat Display", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: table-row;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.headtext {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <img src="assets/img/muProfile.png" alt="wow cool logo" class="coologo">
  <h2 class="headtext name">Muatex</h2>
  <p class="headtext occupation">
    Graphic Designer <br> Web Developer <br>
  </p>
</div>
```

My code is **probably** really messy, *I don't know* but I just need help with this slight problem. Thank you in advance! https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFIOu.png (im new to posting in stack i just made an account for this question)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Just wanted to add, since that resource takes 18 pages to reach it, that flexbox is definitely the preferred layout technique nowadays. You can get some gamified practice in with this https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: a sidenote: `<br>`and `<img>` are empty tags. They dont have a slash to be closed as they also have no closing tag. Using `<br>` inside a paragraph can be valid, however mostly it would be smarter to simply use a new paragraph then. also a <br> right at the end of a paragraph should not be used. Thats what you have a `margin-bottom` for